# What do you call an event that happens without a cause?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary

I used to think those are random events but someone over at [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77002/29481) insists that randomness means something else so I am at a loss here. Can someone help me out?

What do you call an event that happens without a cause?

Comment: spon·ta·ne·ous spänˈtānēəs/ adj. "performed or occurring as a result of a sudden inner impulse or inclination and **without premeditation or external stimulus**." "Happening or arising **without apparent external cause**; self-generated."

Comment: Observer, it is more natural to ask questions like this with the wording "What do you call". Saying "How do you call" is unnatural and not really used by native speakers.

Comment: Does anything happen without a cause?

Comment: Whether something can happen without a cause is an irrelevant philosphical question, and is not necessary to have in order to express the idea in language. Language has to be able to express imaginary ideas, hypotheses that are later refuted, fiction and of course plain old lies.

Comment: @RoaringFish Quantum mechanics

Comment: @Izkata http://xkcd.com/1240/

Comment: God has sometimes been equated with the idea of a 'first cause' - others deny that such a thing is possible. As for QM - surely that depends whether you view it as a literal description of physics, rather than a mathematical model?

Comment: Regarding QM, events without a known or understood cause are not quite the same thing as events without a cause.

Comment: @user3490 Oh, [it's real, not just part of the mathematical model](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=are-virtual-particles-rea)

Comment: @Izkata I was thinking of the probabilistic nature of QM rather than virtual particles in particular. There's no dispute that the predictions of the theory agree with our observations, as you point out, but I think it's a bit of a jump from there to assert that the universe actually operates randomly.

Comment: I wouldn't take that person at physics stackexchange too seriously.  They're using a very narrow definition of "random" that's definitely not agreed to by a majority of physicists or mathematicians.

Comment: I think we call it the big bang...

Comment: @Jonathan It’s a common misconception to think of the big bang as acausal (aided no doubt by the incorrect analogy to a theological “first cause”).

Comment: I wonder what did people at stackexchanges said random meant ? If it's about absence of correlation between events that's merely another way of saying "without a cause". Maybe is it just about the event timing ? If so it looks indeed too restrictive. But maybe it's something else entirely ?

Comment: @kriss - For most of them, *random* is a synonym of *unpredictable*. When going a step further, there is "epistemological randomness" (not enough information has been gathered) and "ontological randomness" (no amount of information helps or it cannot be gathered at all) but that is something physics has yet to turn its attention to.

Comment: @Observer: ok, as I understand it *unpredictable* speaks about timing, you know what eventually *cause* the event but not *when* it will occur (like radioactive disintegration).

Comment: @kriss - Yes. I think *unpredictable* relates to other measurable parameters of an event as well. For example, the shape and the colors of a next cloud in a sky. In addition to predictions there are [retrodictions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrodict) too - an ontologically random event should not reveal any new information about an event of a same kind in the past.

Comment: Actually, radioactive decay is exceedingly predictable (there are tables and very precise measurements) whereas the timing of a volcanic eruption as an example, may be _unpredictable_ (due to our lack of knowledge, data or sophistication of methods).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I would say a *spontaneous* event.

Comment: +1, but I can't vouch that physicists don't have some other meaning for "spontaneous" that they consider more important as well. Cranky lot.

Comment: @T.E.D. we certainly are, but I can't think of a technical meaning that would conflict.  A *quantum* physicist on the other hand...

Comment: @T.E.D. Yeah. Grammar folk are never cranky.

Comment: OK, I'll play the cranky scientist. _Spontaneous_ means an event that can occur without a specific trigger, it does not mean that it has no _cause_. In a non-technical sense, I could _spontaneously break into song_ but I would still have a _reason_ for doing it. Presumably I would be very happy, or drunk or something.

Comment: I remember spontaneous in chemistry as meaning the reaction would just happen when the two reactants came in contact.  A non-spontaneous reaction would require an ignition or heat input.

Baking soda and vinegar react spontaneously.  A match igniting requires a trigger.

Comment: @terdon I think that falls in the philosophy of it all, really. Really, I can think of nothing that does not have a cause... but this word is the best choice in my mind by far, seconded by inexplicable.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore yes but they react _because_ they are in proximity, there is a clear cause, in the case of vinegar and baking soda it is a classic reaction between an acid and a base. In this case, spontaneous just means they don't need a catalyst or any external energy input but there is most definitely a cause. That said, I think _spontaneous_ is pretty close to what the OP wants, as I said before, I am "playing the cranky scientist" and have already joined Pedants Anonymous.

Comment: @AthomSfere see my reply to ChrisCudmore I'm just playing the pedant and have actually up voted this.

Comment: _Spontaneous_ combustion has a very specific meaning. I m not sure you can really use spontaneous to describe without cause.

Answer (score 32):

It seems that the concept *without cause* is not a true criterion. Assuming we are not talking about supernatural events, there are physical, biological, social, political things that happened that contributed to the ultimate event.

The real sense behind the phrase is *no known cause* or *no understood cause*. I would therefore propose **[inexplicable](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inexplicable)**

> not capable of explanation; unexplainable

Comment: What you say may turn out to be true, but it's essentially a philosophical position. Linguistically, I think you could still assert that the word "causeless" has an underlying 'basic' meaning of "without cause" on some level -- even though, as you say, it might turn out that in real-world pragmatics that effectively boils down to "without *known* cause" or "without *directly detectable* cause" etc.

Comment: @NeilCoffey The phrase *without a cause* can have numerous denotative and connotative meanings. Consider the film *Rebel without a Cause*. There are numerous indications of factors (causes) contributing to the characters' rebellion, but they all lack a commitment to a principle (a cause).

Comment: There are two sides to this: One is the disposition of said event and the other is the understanding of the event by the observer. To the extent that the Observer may not be able to explain the cause makes INEXPLICABLE a good choice. As to the root nature of the event however, the fact that the observer cannot explain the cause does not impact the facts around the cause itself. It could be argued that every event has a cause - it is only our lack of understanding that makes it INEXPLICABLE or believe it to be chaotic.

Comment: Things may happen without a reason, but they never happen without a cause.

Comment: @bib I agree, but that's of course not really the use of 'without cause' that I'm referring to. (Write it as a formal logic expression if it helps to avoid this kind of silly argument.)

Answer (score 21):

Well, there is always the word **causeless**: so you could simply say a **causeless event**. A rough synonym is **fortuitous**.

You could potentially say a **random event** or **chance event**.

The commentators on the physics forum are correct: as a scientific term, that isn't the technical meaning of **random**. But unless you're intending to use it as a technical term, so what? -- there are plenty of words that have a different everyday meaning to their technical meaning.

Comment: `there are plenty of words that have a different everyday meaning to their technical meaning.`  That is unfortunately true, literally!

Comment: "Fortuitous" gets my vote.

Comment: Causeless makes a determination that the event had no cause (arguable) and does not consider that it was simply beyond the observer to understand it. Fortuitous as a primary definition may be appropriate but leans toward an event that was of good fortune (versus bad), which the OP did not imply.

Answer (score 19):

From OED...

> **acausal** *- not causal; independent of or not involving the relationship of cause and effect.*

---

[Here's an NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acausal&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) showing how usage has increased during the [Quantum era](http://www.science20.com/nithyanand_rao/how_the_quantum_era_really_began) it fits so well with.

[image]

Comment: Looking it up in the OED is cheating :). Good find, +1.

Comment: @terdon: I honestly couldn't say whether I actually *remembered* coming across it, or just took it for granted that it was bound exist (standard ***a-*** prefix meaning "without"). But I had OED open, and it was easier to get a definition there than fight Google telling me I probably meant to search for *define **causal***

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder if acausal events have actually increased since the Quantum era. ;-P

Answer (score 9):

How about *unprecipitated* or *unprompted*?

Comment: Unprompted literally translates to French as *impromptu*, which, taken back into English, has a much closer meaning to "without a cause" than unprompted. Impromptu includes the concept of spontaneity, whereas unprompted simply means "without being encouraged or assisted to say or do something".

Answer (score 5):

*Random* neither implies nor precludes a cause in itself.  *Causeless* is an option: [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Causeless): "having no justifying cause or reason"

Answer (score 2):

Yes random events are not necessarily causeless. I can think of a few words:

[***unincited***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unincited)

[***unprovoked***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unprovoked)

[***uninduced***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uninduced?s=t)

Comment: It's easily understood, but I must admit I've never come across *unincited* before. The spellchecker in my Google Chrome browser doesn't recognise it, and it ["flatlines" in NGrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unincited%2Cunprovoked&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) by comparison with *unprovoked* (and even by comparison with [the latest technical buzzword "acausal"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unincited%2Cacausal&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)).

Comment: How about ***unsolicited***?

Comment: Unincited is simply morphology at work: un plus a word. Not every possible English word is in dictionaries or in wide use, just like not every possible English sentence has been written down and cataloged as part of the language. Of course dictionaries do not list every possible "un" word; it is space-wasting and counterproductive to do so. Also, it's just a quirk of orthography that "un" is written without a space from the word that follows. What if the rules for writing were such that it was written "un incited"? Then of course, both words would be in your dictionary, and that is that.

Answer (score 2):

A non-deterministic event. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminism.

Non-causal or acausal are also used in filter & systems theory.

Answer (score 2):

An "act of God" is often used to denote an event that is out of anyone's control, and therefore "just happens".  As a non-believer, I must confess a certain pleasure in describing "an event that happens without a cause" as an "act of God."

Comment: The French language root (and is used in many English legal papers) is "Force Majeure" and whilst providing a very vague definition, hearkens to the days when, lacking facts, people believed the Earth was flat, our Sun revolved around the Earth, etc. There are probably better answers here to describe the case of an observer who does not understand the cause behind an event versus accepting that events are without cause or that the Earth is flat - conditions that simply punctuate our lack of understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

For a more literary word choice, you could also consider **deus ex machina** to explain things without apparent, erm, explanation.

Latin for "God from the machine", it's a plot cliche first lamented by Horace way back in the day. As the translation implies, it used to literally mean having a god (usually Zeus) descend down at the climax of a play or story to conveniently intervene and solve whatever problems were being presented.

Today the term is usually used to describe media where an event happens seemingly out of the blue. For example, the Naval officer passing by at the end of William Golding's The Lord of The Flies who rescues the boys, or the various machinations of Douglas Adams's Infinite Improbability Drive.

In any case, an event with no obvious cause, especially one which thwarts expectations or otherwise introduces chaos, is by definition a *deus ex machina*, since any explanation you ascribe to it is as good as the next.

Comment: The problem is that *deus ex machina* cannot be easily disentangled of its connotations of "cheesy plot twist" so that it can be used to simply denote a causeless event.

Comment: I agree completely, I think deus ex machina requires a certain context and connotation, I just like options when I'm picking words to describe things.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on context also consider [***self-generated***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/self-generated?s=t)

> ***self-generated*** adjective
>   1.  happening or arising without apparent external cause; "spontaneous laughter"; "spontaneous combustion"; "a spontaneous abortion" [syn: spontaneous] [ant: induced]
>   2.  originating from the self

Another apt word is ***unengendered*** from

[***engender***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=engender&searchmode=none)

> *etymology* engender (v.) Look up engender at Dictionary.com
>   early 14c., "beget, procreate," from Old French engendrer (12c.) "engender, beget, bear; cause, bring about," from Latin ingenerare "to implant, engender, produce," from in- "in" (see in- (2)) + generare "beget, create" (see generation). Meaning "cause, produce" is mid-14c. Related: Engendered; engendering.

Other alternatives along similar etymological lines are

***unbegotten***

***eternal***

giving the sense of having no beginning or cause (self-existent).

> en·gen·der verb \in-ˈjen-dər, en-\
>   : to be the source or cause of (something)

Answer (score 0):

noncausal

a spontaneous event is an event that happens spontaneously like a spring not with out a cause necessarily

Answer (score 0):

The word I have most seen in this context is, quite simply, **[uncaused](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uncaused?s=t)**.

Answer (score -1):

Idiopathic seems like the right choice.

https://www.google.com/search?q=ideopathic&oq=ideopathic&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.1768j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: _Idiopathic_ is just a fancy word we use in the biological sciences to mean _I dunno why_. It is used to indicate, for example, that the cause of a patient's illness is something specific to that patient, not that there is no cause.

Comment: And doesn't the suffix pathic imply pathological?

Answer (score -1):

an event without cause, should be the first event of history. it's called God, according to Assisi AFAIK.

To speak to a wider audience without rejection (on religious grounds), you may call this a "god-event" ala the so-called '[god-particle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson)'

Comment: This assumes that there **is** a primary event, and secondly that there is only one. If there can be multiple primary events, then time effectively has multiple independent starting points.

Comment: @NewAlexandria: Yeah, nice edit. sincerely.